# Android - phone idle can't catch network packets

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp

I've written an app with a Service listening for incoming broadcast UDP packets. It works fine, starts an activity when receives "OK", but when the phone goes idle (with the screen off) it seems the service stops listening to packets. Just turn on the screen and it works fine again.

The service doesn't really stop, I put some Log() commands in it and I can see in logcat that it's still running. It just can't catch network packets when the screen is off.
To ensure the service will run I added a startForeground() command but that didn't solve the issue.
Also tried with wakelock.acquire() with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK flag, to keep the CPU active, still doesn't work.

Is there anything in the system that stops network activity when the phone goes idle? I don't think so. How do whatsapp, facebook, ecc...? Even when the phone is idle they are able to get data and notificate when you receive a new message. Pherhaps they intiate a client side connection, instead I'd need to listen for incoming UDP packets.

Here's an extract of the code:

```
public class UDPlistener extends Service {
private DatagramSocket UDPsocket;
String result;
Intent myIntent;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
Log.e("UDPlistener","onCreate");

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle("UDP listener")
.setContentText("UDP listener ")
.setContentIntent(pIntent)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.build();
startForeground(1, noti);

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wakelock.acquire();

new Thread( new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
  try {
  Log.i("UDPlistener","Start listening...");
  UDPsocket = new DatagramSocket(9999);
  byte[] receiveData = new byte[64];
  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
  UDPsocket.receive(receivePacket);
  if (receiveData.length > 0) {
    result = new String(receivePacket.getData());
  } else {
    result = "";
  }

  if (result.length() > 1 && (result.substring(0,2)).equals("OK")) {
    //Start activity
    if (myIntent == null) {
      myIntent = new Intent(UDPlistener.this, UDPactivity.class);
      myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
      }
    startActivity(myIntent);
  } 

  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    Log.e("UDPlistener","UnknownHostException");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
    Log.e("UDPlistener","SocketTimeoutException");
    //e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SocketException e) {
    Log.e("UDPlistener","SocketException");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("UDPlistener","IOException");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("UDPlistener","Generic Exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    UDPsocket.close();
  } //try
}
}).start();
super.onCreate();
} //onCreate


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  Log.e("UDPlistener","onDestroy");
  UDPsocket.close();
  wakelock.release();
  super.onDestroy();
} //onDestroy
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Try looking at the official Android Email app's source code: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/5d886036876ffbba962a90e5732104cda387bf32/emailsync/src/com/android/emailsync/SyncManager.java#L991

Comment: @swooby Thanks for the link. This Email app's source code uses WakeLock but I found that WakeLock is not the right way, or not enough, to do it. Wakelock only keeps screen and/or CPU awake, but also WiFi goes idle. There are _WifiManager.WifiLock_ and _WifiManager.MulticastLock_ to keep it on. I tried both, even in combination with WakeLock but still can't get it. I keep working on it, I'd like to solve this. I'll read carefully the email app's source code trying to understand where, when and how it checks for new incoming mails.